# Discrete Math Probability and Random Variable review question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

I can't solve this question on my review. If anyone can give me some help to start it, it would be appreciated!

Consider an experiment that is successful with probability 0.8. We repeat
this experiment (independently) until it is successful for the first time. The first 5 times we
do the experiment, we have to pay 10 dollars per experiment. After this, we have to pay 5 dollars per
1 experiment. Define the random variable X to be the total amount of money that we have
to pay during all experiments. Determine the expected value E(X).

EDIT:

Do it use E(X) = 1/p

so 1/0.8* 10 = 12.5

the answer is 12.5$?

Comment: Don't change the question to a completely different one after getting an answer. That is not how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance (and inelegantly) I think it should be $$(.8)(\$10)+(.2)^1(.8)(\$20)+(.2)^2(.8)(\$30)+(.2)^3(.8)(\$40)+(.2)^4(.8)(\$50)+\sum\limits_{n=5}^\infty{.2^n(.8)(\$50+(n-4)\$5)}$$

Each term in the series represents an ending point to the whole experiment. There is an 80% chance it ends with a \$10 payment, 20%$\times$80% chance it ends with a \$20 payment, etc.

I could be wrong, but here's a diagram of all the outcomes.  The experiment has to end at one of the dollar amounts.  And the probability of that ending is the product of all the paths to get there.

[image]

Comment: hi, why is the first value 0.8*10, when whether or not you succeed or fail, you have to pay increments of 10?

Comment: I was thinking of it in terms a a lot of decision branches (that only go one way like the one on the left here http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/basic/control/branching/decision.gif).  So, there's a 80% chance you pay \$10, do one experiment and are done. There is a (20%)(80%) chance you'll fail once and succeed the second time for \$20.  There's a (20%)(20%)(80%) chance you'll fail, fail, succeed. For \$30. Etc.

Comment: To better address your comment, it's .8*10 because paying the 10 when you fail is accounted for by incrementing the payment amount in later terms in the series.

Comment: but why is it 80% chance to pay 10$. don't you have to pay 10 dollar the first experiment anyway?

Comment: Yes.  My solution is saying, there's an 80% chance you will have to pay \$10 and that's it and a 20% chance you'll have to pay \$10 plus another amount.  Another way to look at it would be to pull the \$10 and put it out front and take away \$10 from all the other terms.  That would align with how you're thinking.  $\$10 + (.8)(0) + (.2)(.8)(\$10)...$

Comment: @NeedHelp remember that though you have to pay \$10 no matter outcome of first experiment, it is the case only when the first experiment exceed that you only need to pay just \$10. Otherwise you dont stop until succeed and pay more

Comment: I added an image of how I read the problem.  Hopefully that helps (and hopefully I'm correct).